# Parsing JSON in javascript for multiple browsers

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying two different approaches. One works in only Firefox, the other works in Safari, but neither work in both. The one that works in Firefox is:

```
 var json = JSON.parse(data);
 var results = json.query.results.quote;
```

The one that works in Safari

```
 var results = data.query.results.quote;
```

Where data is the JSON that is being returned from a server. Is one of these the proper ways to parse JSON, and what's the best way for browser compatibility

EDIT:
When I debug in Safari using `JSON.parse` I get the error: `Unexpected identifier "object"`

Comment: `data` appears to already be an object. In that case, don't parse.

Comment: Which version of Safari are you running? JSON support landed with 4.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas When I don't parse, firebug gives me the error: `data.query is undefined`

Comment: Is `data` the result of a jQuery AJAX call?  If so, jQuery is probably parsing it for you already.

Comment: @RocketHazmat it is coming from a jQuery Ajax call

Comment: @Chris: Post your code so that people don't have to try to guess what's going on. It takes for too much time doing it that way.

Comment: @Chris: I suggest adding `dataType: 'json'` to that call.  That will make jQuery handle the parsing for you.

Comment: @RocketHazmat that did the trick. Thank you :) Wanna add that as an answer I can mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery to get this JSON data, you don't need to worry about parsing it.  jQuery can (and sometimes will) do it for you.

Your problem is (probably) that it is already being parsed for you.  If you server returns the `Content-type: application/json` header, jQuery will parse it for you.  If it returns a different header, like `text/html`, then it won't be parsed as JSON.  It's never good to be unsure of what a variable contains.

To tell jQuery to always parse it as JSON, use `dataType: 'json'`.  This makes sure that the data in your callback is *always* an object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        var results = data.query.results.quote;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official implementation of JSON by Douglas Crockford. It's available [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). Major libraries make sure to add JSON functionality. It is also very easy to check if a native implementation of JSON is available within the existing browser.

The JSON library already does that. It checks to see if the browser already has `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` implemented. If it does, it won't override anything. If it doesn't it will give you the functionality you need.

Comment: When I try `JSON.parse` in Safari, I'm getting the error: `Unexpected identifier "object"`

Comment: Native JSON. I'll check out the lib

Comment: the JSON's coming from here: `http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22s%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys`